# FB.login suddenly showing interstial screens, not returning

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am releasing TODAY a web app that has been working fine until this morning. Suddenly, calls to FB.login() force the user to go through interstitial screens to install chat and then the login DOES NOT RETURN to the calling app. What the heck??

I made no changes at all to the login flow.

Is anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 0):

From the Facebook dev support site, they're looking into it (high priority): 
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129554187241898?browse=search_518d47a000a112f11767421